# Most efficient way to sustain a maximum number of entries in SQL Server database table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

I was wondering, what is the most efficient way of doing the following?

I'm trying to implement some sort of an auditing system where each logon to my page will be stored in a database. I use SQL Server 2005 database. The table that stores the auditing data obviously cannot grow without an upper limit. So, say, it should have a maximum of 1000 entries and then any older entries must be deleted when new ones are inserted. The question is how do you do this in a most efficient way -- do I need to add any special columns, like, say an ordinal entry number for easier clean-up?

EDIT:
Say, if the structure of my table is (pseudo code):

```
`id` BIGINT autoincrement
`date` DATETIME
`data1` NVARCHAR(256)
`data2` INT
```

How would you write this cleanup procedure?

Comment: A fixed number of records with a fixed size per record sounds like a circular queue. In which case every "insert" could actually be an update (if you pre-poulate, or merge/upsert if not) based on a modulo of a sequence. ie update audit_table set date=..., data1=..., data2=... where id = sequence%1000. Index on date will still be busy. Perhaps a bit radical and not very databasish. I haven't done this myself. I tend to partitioning and pruning off old data. Or for using os logging with rolling log files, the activet one viewable by an external table (Oracle world).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tony mentioned, use dates to identify the inserts. In addition, use a clustered index on the date field, so that inserts are always at the end of the table and it is easy and efficient to scan through and delete the old rows.

If you use a number, something like this should work:

```
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE someField < (SELECT MAX(someField) - 1000 FROM myTable)
```

For a date, deleting everything older than one day would be something like:

```
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE someField < DateAdd('d', -1, getdate())
```

Comment: But if I do it by date, how do I maintain a fixed number of entries (1000 in my question)?

Comment: You can use numbers.  Dates are more efficient only because they can be calculated on the client, rather than needing the (admittedly very small) overhead of the increment column

Comment: You still want the clustered index on whatever column represents the ordering, though

Comment: Sorry, I don't know SQL that well, can you elaborate? I edited my original post with a data structure.

Comment: Finally, does it have to be *exactly* 1000?  I'd assume, say, a few days worth would work, no?

Comment: 1000 is something I used here for the sake of a simple calculation. In reality the number will be 1,000,000 or more. So can you give me an SQL example and we'll see if it makes it faster with dates?

Comment: Thanks. IDK, in my opinion MAX is much faster than calling DateAdd on each entry. Plus if I use the primary index auto increment field for your 'someField', I'd also save one index. May be just my opinion though...

Comment: In this case max requires a query, and the dateadd its only called once. The latter is much more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Do it by date not number. Have a look at your stats, see how many days 1000 is / will be. Delete anything older than that. Auditing is never particularly efficient, but if you have loads of data that doesn't help you that's very inefficient....

Comment: You mean sorting by date could be more efficient than sorting by, say, BIGINT auto increment field?

Comment: Sorting is effectively irrelevant given you have an index. One broken piece of code and your last 1000 records could all be for one person. Last 1000 is too simple to be useful unless you are lucky, I'd be more comforatble with say at least 1 (month ?) logins for each user.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your needs, this should work. I've tested it on SQL 2008R2, but I can not see any reason why it would not work on SQL Server 2005.

1. Use a logon trigger to insert a row into your audit table.
2. Create an AFTER INSERT trigger on your audit table that deletes the row with MIN(ID).

Here's some code to play with:

/* Create audit table */

```
CREATE TABLE ServerLogonHistory
(SystemUser VARCHAR(512),
ID BIGINT,
DBUser VARCHAR(512),
SPID INT,
LogonTime DATETIME)
GO
```

/* Create Logon Trigger */

```
CREATE TRIGGER Tr_ServerLogon
ON ALL SERVER FOR LOGON
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO TestDB.dbo.ServerLogonHistory
SELECT SYSTEM_USER, MAX(ID)+1 , USER,@@SPID,GETDATE()
FROM TestDB.dbo.ServerLogonHistory;
END
GO
```

/* Create the cleanup trigger */

```
CREATE TRIGGER AfterLogin
ON TestDB.dbo.ServerLogonHistory
AFTER INSERT
AS
DELETE 
FROM TestDB.dbo.ServerLogonHistory 
WHERE ID = 
(SELECT MIN(ID) FROM TestDB.dbo.ServerLogonHistory);
GO;
```

A word of warning. If you create an invalid logon trigger, you'll not be able to logon to the database. But don't panic! It's all part of learning. You'll be able to use 'sqlcmd' to drop the bad trigger.

I did try to delete the row with the min ID in the logon trigger, but I was not able to get that to work.

Comment: Of course you can create your cleanup trigger once you're audit table contains the number of row you need/want. Then at that point, the oldest row will be deleted whenever a row is inserted.

Comment: @ahmd0 - I probably suggested a more complex solution than you need. I was thinking you needed to record logins to the database itself. Now I see you probably are taking about login to your website. If the latter is the case, then dispense with the logon trigger. If your audit table is working and capturing what you need, then create the "cleanup" trigger on the table. The trigger will delete one row for every new row inserted.

Answer (score 1):

Is the "ID"  column a Identity column with step 1?

after you insert one row

*delete column where id<IDENTITY_CURRENT(YOUR_TABLE)-1000*

Comment: Interesting, thank you. I'm assuming IDENTITY_CURRENT is some internal variable that doesn not involve any select's, right?

Comment: IDENTITY_CURRENT will return the latest value of the identity column of your table.